# Implementing UITabBarControllerDelegate does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a new class to implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, but the method in the class does not been invoked.

**AppDelegate.swift**:

```
func application() {
  // ...

  let controller = MyTabItemController()
  let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
  tabBarController.viewControllers = [controller]
  tabBarController.delegate = MyTabBarControllerDelegate()

  self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

  // ...
}
```

**MyTabBarControllerDelegate.swift**:

```
class MyTabBarControllerDelegate: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate{
  func tabBarController(/*...*/) {
    print("method invoked")
  }
}
```

When I selected the item, the message `"method invoked"` is not shown.

If I let `AppDelegate` extend `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, everything worked well and the message is shown in console.

I want to know why this happened?

Comment: Any particular reason for creating a separate class for tabbarController delegate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delegate` property of `UITabBarController` is *weak*. Thus, your delegate is released directly after the assignment. You should keep you delegate object by a strong reference.